# How do I export tslint static analyzer cyclomatic complexity report in vscode?

Tags: json, typescript, report, tslint, cyclomatic-complexity

I want to export tslint cyclomatic complexity report in any format like json, csv, tsv etc.

How can I do that ?
Are there any third party libraries available in the market ?

Currently I am using [tslint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) extension in my vscode.

Please help